# How do I replace or modify this circuit to run on 7.4VDC?

Tags: circuit-design, opto-isolator

I’m trying to replace the power supply of a CCTV camera with something that will accept a 7.4V battery.

The part I’m stuck on is using or replacing the optocoupler with something that can be driven by a DC voltage.

If I understand it correctly, that part of the circuit is for a 50 or 60Hz “line lock” pulse generator. I'm not entirely sure what its purpose is but I’m pretty sure I need it.

[image]

Comment: Have you confirmed that the CCTV camera will operate for long enough on the size of battery you're intending to use?

Comment: I'm sure I saw another question on EE.SE that was asking a very similar question, but I can't locate it now. You can get 50 Hz generator ICs like the [ELM446](https://www.elmelectronics.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/ELM446DS.pdf) that just need a cheap crystal and three capacitors.

Comment: If you need the FP output then you'll need to run it from local AC or, make a little oscillator that produces an accurate 50/60 Hz signal.

Comment: Maybe you could pick up the ambient lighting ripple with a phototransistor, AC couple/DC reject (PLL?) and divide it by two for a similar signal. Assuming it doesn't simply work without the signal or an ersatz mains frequency oscillator.

Answer (score 1):

"Line lock" ought to be a signal so the microprocessor can synchronize the camera shutter to the power line frequency.  When the shutter isn't synchronized to the power line you will get rolling bars in the camera picture if there's a light flickering at line frequency.  LED lights are especially bad at that. Fluorescent bulbs are bad, too.  Even plain old incandescent bulbs can do so, though usually not as badly as the others.

Without the line lock, there'll be nothing for the camera to synchronize to - you'll get rolling bars in the picture under artificial lighting.

The bigger question is whether or not the camera will even work without the line lock.  The software in the microprocessor may refuse to operate the shutter if line lock is missing.  There's really no way to tell what it will do.  You'll have to try it.

Disconnect line lock and power the camera with its built in power supply.  If it works, yippee!  If not, you could include a small circuit (555 timer or something) to provide a 50 or 60 Hz signal.

It won't work properly under artificial light, but maybe that won't be a problem.  If you are using it under natural sunlight, that'd OK.

Answer (score 0):

The camera only need 12V, this means you can use a 3.7V LiIon-call and a StepUp voltage regulator to get this voltage.

If the current is not so high (12V/500mA), then the MT3608 could work for you.

If it is necessary that the camera get a 50Hz or 60Hz signal, then you can create a signal with a NE555 or an other source.

It is not useful to modify this power-supply what you get to the camera.

The 5V are generated on the camera-board and the F, P, Out is the pin which need the 50 or 60Hz.